# If meta key's value is x then echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 pieces of code that essentially should do the same thing, but none of them are working and they are all echoing "Not Working!".

The meta key is wilcity_belongs_to and the value is 2980. These are all based on what plan a listing is on. So if the listing plan is value 2980 then it must echo "Working!".

```
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wilcity_belongs_to',true );
if( $meta == '2980' ) {
    echo "Working!";
} else {
    echo "Not Working!";
};
```

and

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results( "select * from $wpdb->wpam_postmeta where meta_key = 'wilcity_belongs_to' " );
if ( $wilcity_belongs_to == '2980') {
    echo "Working!";
} else {
    echo "Not Working!";
};
```

and

```
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wilcity_belongs_to', true ) == '2980' ) {
    echo "Working!";
} else {
    echo "Not Working!";
};
```

Here is a screenshot of what is in the database: [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYHxd.png)
This is in Table: wpam_postmeta

Please could i get help on this, ive been trying everything.

Comment: Did you verify the actual value of `$meta`? `var_dump($meta);`

Comment: Ive never used var_dump before so i added it in both echo's and got a return of Not Working!bool(false) so not sure whats wrong then

Comment: 1 - Enable WordPress Debugging With WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_LOG in the wp-config.php

Comment: @SiavashEbrahimi Thank you, i got this: WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where meta_key = 'wilcity_belongs_to'' at line 1 for query select * from  where meta_key = 'wilcity_belongs_to'  made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include('/themes/wilcity-childtheme/functions.php')

Comment: Table $wpdb->wpam_postmeta not exists ! Check the table name

Comment: What does `var_dump( get_the_ID() )` returns? Are you getting meta value within loop? `get_post_meta` will return `false` if id is not correct

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka got a false there too, but dont know why it is so

Comment: @SiavashEbrahimi i checked database and wpam_postmeta is the right table in the database

Comment: My guess you get it out of the loop as `get_the_ID` [returns](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) (int|false) The ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop. False if $post is not set. Need information where are calling `get_post_meta` (which template, is it within loop or not). Also you may try to use `get_queried_object_id()` instead

Comment: @Ryan I think $wpdb->wpam_postmeta is not registered. you must write it like this : $wpdb->prefix . 'wpam_postmeta'

Comment: The first example will only work if inside the loop. #2 will only work if you update your code to `$wpdb->postmeta`  or `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta`, or `wpam_postmeta`.  #3 will only work if `$post` global is defined.  Since you're only including brief snippets of code, it will be difficult for someone to give you a good answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way? `get_results()` usually returns an array with the result set.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "select * from $wpdb->wpam_postmeta where meta_key = 'wilcity_belongs_to' " );
foreach ($result as $row) {
   if ( $row["wilcity_belongs_to"] == '2980') {
       echo "Working!";
   } else {
       echo "Not Working!";
   };
};
```

Comment: Still got a Not Working! echo

Comment: @Ryan sry... get_results() returns an array of results. i added a foreach()

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately now it isnt echoing anything